# How to rotate to Y axis label in nvd3 chart

Tags: nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I have a multi chart in nvd3. I need to rotate the y axis labels for both yAxis1 and yAxis2. But i see there is no good option for rotating y axislabels. For rotating xAxis label it is pretty straight forward. Just uisng `rotateLabels: 45` works for xAxis. But for y axis this solution doesn't work.I tried to use the `rotateLabels` inside `yAxis:{}` as following:

```
rotateLabels: 45
```

It works for x axis. But it doesn't work for y axis.
I also tried using css commands like

```
css:{'transform':'rotate(45)'}
```

But nothing works at all. I cant think of any other solution.

Any one have any idea for me how can i rote the y axis labels in nvd3 chart?
Thanks in advance

Comment: As per the documentation of nvd3 rotateLabels is only made for X axes. Try CSS property `css : { 'transform': 'rotate(45deg)'} `

Comment: it also does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not rotate y axis label from the chart options like this. You can do this by making just little modification in the library. Go to `nvd3.js` code. and find the switch block

```
 switch (axis.orient()) {}
```

And inside this block you will find

```
case 'top':
case 'bottom':
case 'right':
case 'left':
```

Here `case 'left'` and `case 'right'` are for y axes. So go inside these cases and find:

`axisLabel
    .style('text-anchor', rotateYLabel ? 'middle' : 'begin')
    .attr('transform', rotateYLabel ? 'rotate(90)' : '')`
Now instead of `rotate(90)` put `rotate(45)` and you are all set. If you want to change other y axes property you can also change inside these case blocks.

But if you still want to modify from front end the you can select the dom element using d3 like

```
d3.select(".nv-y2").select(".nvd3").select("text").attr("transform","rotate(45)");
```

Any one of the above strategies should work.